# Can vectorization be done? will it do any good?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

This function here is eating a lot of time in my run. But what is see is the most of the time goes in the inbuilt function `polyarea`. Can this code be vectorized for performance boost?

Profiler Report -

```
  time   calls
                  1 function [S S_area] = Polygons_intersection_Compute_area(S)
                  2 % Guillaume JACQUENOT
                  3 % guillaume at jacquenot at gmail dot com
                  4 % 2007_10_08
                  5 % 2009_06_16
                  6 % Compute area of each polygon of in S.
                  7 % Results are stored as a field in S
                  8 
  0.50   51945    9 S_area = struct('A', {}); 
  0.20   51945   10 for i=1:numel(S) 
  0.28  103890   11     S(i).area = 0; 
  1.34  103890   12     S_area(i).A = zeros(1,numel(S(i).P)); 
  0.69  103890   13     for j=1:numel(S(i).P) 
  9.24  103890   14         S_area(i).A(j) = polyarea(S(i).P(j).x,S(i).P(j).y); 
  0.28  103890   15         S(i).area      = S(i).area + (1-2*S(i).P(j).hole) * S_area(i).A(j);         
  0.01  103890   16     end 
  0.08  103890   17 end
```

Comment: I'd say that 9 seconds for 100k calls is not too bad.

Comment: @Jonas- Thanks for your input.Actually, that is what i want to know, is it not bad, or there is still some way we can juice out some extra time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 4 issues. I'll discuss them in increasing order of potential performance gain.

First: you use `i` and `j` as loop variable names. These are also the names of the imaginary unit in Matlab, which means Matlab will have to spend some time looking up which one you mean. Thing is, it has to do that *on each iteration* if the loop is not JIT'ed (which yours isn't, I'll get to that).

Second: indexing multi-dimensional structures takes more time than you think. Multi-D structures are somewhat notorious in this respect, and you had better avoid too many indexing operations on them. Often making a simple copy of an element, doing all your operations on that copy, and then writing the copy back to the structure can increase performance quite a bit.

Third: you don't pre-allocate `S_area` in the most efficient way. You don't even pre-allocate the structure, but grow it in the first loop when you pre-allocate `S_area(i).A`. This can all be improved (see below).

Fourth: `polyarea` is *not* a built-in function, and so this double-loop will not be JIT'ed. If you call *any* function inside a loop that either you or the Mathworks wrote in M-language (rather than C), the JIT compiler will be unable to compile your loop. This is *by far* the most annoying (and improvable) limitation in the JIT framework, while JIT'ed loops can often run a factor of 100 or more faster than non-JIT'ed loops.

The only solution often is to "inline" a non-builtin function in the loop body. In Matlab that means: copy-paste the entire contents of the function body into the loop, and do this recursively for all non-builtin functions called in that body.

All of the above leads to this version of your code:

```
% pre-allocate S_area
S_area(numel(S)).A = [];
As = cellfun(@(x) zeros(numel(x),1), {S.P}, 'UniformOutput', false);
[S_area.A] = deal(As{:});

% number of polygons for all S(ii)
numPolys = cellfun(@numel, {S.P});

% enter loop
for ii = 1:numel(S)
    % extract S(ii) only once
    Sii = S(ii);

    Sii.area = 0;
    Aii = S_area(ii).A;        
    for jj = 1:numPolys(ii)

        p = Sii.P(jj);  % extract polygon only once
        x = p.x; % and its x and y components
        y = p.y;            
        sz = size(p);

        % NOTE: core of polyarea. Note that all checks and flexibility, and 
        % therefore user-friendliness, is GONE. Very little has to go wrong 
        % here before a hard-to-understand error is issued. 
        Area = reshape(abs(sum( (x([2:sz(1) 1],:) - x(:,:)).* ...
            (y([2:sz(1) 1],:) + y(:,:)))/2),[1 sz(2:end)]);

        Aii(jj) = Area;
        Sii.area = Sii.area + Area*(1-2*p.hole);
    end

    % place copies back into the strucure
    S_area(ii).A = Aii;
    S(ii).area = Sii.area;

end
```

I could not test this as properly as you can, so if you find some errors, please let me know and I'll try to correct them.

Comment: +1 for nice explanations. A few suggestions, though: (1) do not use `arrayfun`, (2) calculate `numel(S(i).P)` and replace the `numel` calls. (3) most likely, you can replace/remove the `size` call as well as reshaping.

Comment: @Rody - Thanks for this detailed answer. I'm very new to matlab, and your explanations are very helpful, not only for this problem, but for my overall understanding of Matlab. 

I tried your version of the code, and it ran perfectly. But there is no improvement in the time, in fact it took half a second more. I guess its like what Jonas said, maybe there is no space for any improvements(in terms of time) in this code. What do you think?

Comment: @Vikram: What version of Matlab do you have?

Comment: @Vikram: Strange...how big on average are your `S`-structures?